# find specific text and append it to specific portions of a text file php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have text files that are being imported from field instruments. The output file is '`txt`' and appears as below;

```
    AUTO DATA  51            
  DATE       TIME     FID BACKGROUND        FID CONCENTRATION                   GPS DATA                
---------  --------  --------------------  -------------------------------------------------------------
15 MAY 16  08:38:35     0.0 PPM OK            8.7 PPM OK          37.46009 -121.94495   32  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:38:40     0.0 PPM OK            9.5 PPM OK          37.46009 -121.94495   32  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:38:45     0.0 PPM OK            119 PPM HIGH_ALRM   37.46009 -121.94495   32  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:38:50     0.0 PPM OK           53.4 PPM HIGH_ALRM   37.46009 -121.94495   32  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:38:55     0.0 PPM OK           36.3 PPM OK          37.46009 -121.94495   32 21  4 

AUTO DATA  52           
  DATE       TIME     FID BACKGROUND        FID CONCENTRATION                   GPS DATA                
---------  --------  --------------------  -------------------------------------------------------------
15 MAY 16  08:40:27     0.0 PPM OK           21.2 PPM OK          37.45982 -121.94486   26  7  6 
15 MAY 16  08:40:32     0.0 PPM OK           17.7 PPM OK          37.45982 -121.94486   26  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:40:37     0.0 PPM OK           17.5 PPM OK          37.45979 -121.94493   26  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:40:42     0.0 PPM OK           12.5 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94502   27  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:40:47     0.0 PPM OK           13.6 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94504   27  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:40:52     0.0 PPM OK           16.9 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94504   27  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:40:57     0.0 PPM OK           18.0 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94504   27  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:41:02     0.0 PPM OK           31.6 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94504   27  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:41:07     0.0 PPM OK           28.4 PPM OK          37.45971 -121.94518   23  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:41:12     0.0 PPM OK           23.6 PPM OK          37.45968 -121.94518   21  7  6 
15 MAY 16  08:41:17     0.0 PPM OK           63.5 PPM OK          37.45968 -121.94518   21  7  6 
15 MAY 16  08:41:22     0.0 PPM OK            294 PPM HIGH_ALRM   37.45968 -121.94518   21  7  6 
15 MAY 16  08:41:27     0.0 PPM OK            212 PPM HIGH_ALRM   37.45968 -121.94518   21  7  5 

AUTO DATA  53           
  DATE       TIME     FID BACKGROUND        FID CONCENTRATION                   GPS DATA                
---------  --------  --------------------  -------------------------------------------------------------
15 MAY 16  08:42:46     0.0 PPM OK           21.0 PPM OK          37.45963 -121.94547   23  6  7 
15 MAY 16  08:42:51     0.0 PPM OK           27.3 PPM OK          37.45963 -121.94547   23  7  5
```

What I need to do is grab the `AUTO DATA *` number and append it to all rows proceeding it, then change to the next number, rinse and repeat and produce something like;

```
AUTO DATA  51            
  DATE       TIME     FID BACKGROUND        FID CONCENTRATION                   GPS DATA                
---------  --------  --------------------  -------------------------------------------------------------
51 15 MAY 16  08:38:35     0.0 PPM OK            8.7 PPM OK          37.46009 -121.94495   32  6  7 
51 15 MAY 16  08:38:40     0.0 PPM OK            9.5 PPM OK          37.46009 -121.94495   32  6  7 
51 15 MAY 16  08:38:45     0.0 PPM OK            119 PPM HIGH_ALRM   37.46009 -121.94495   32  6  7 
51 15 MAY 16  08:38:50     0.0 PPM OK           53.4 PPM HIGH_ALRM   37.46009 -121.94495   32  6  7 
51 15 MAY 16  08:38:55     0.0 PPM OK           36.3 PPM OK          37.46009 -121.94495   32 21  4 

AUTO DATA  52           
  DATE       TIME     FID BACKGROUND        FID CONCENTRATION                   GPS DATA                
---------  --------  --------------------  -------------------------------------------------------------
52 15 MAY 16  08:40:27     0.0 PPM OK           21.2 PPM OK          37.45982 -121.94486   26  7  6 
52 15 MAY 16  08:40:32     0.0 PPM OK           17.7 PPM OK          37.45982 -121.94486   26  6  7 
52 15 MAY 16  08:40:37     0.0 PPM OK           17.5 PPM OK          37.45979 -121.94493   26  6  7 
52 15 MAY 16  08:40:42     0.0 PPM OK           12.5 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94502   27  6  7 
52 15 MAY 16  08:40:47     0.0 PPM OK           13.6 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94504   27  6  7 
52 15 MAY 16  08:40:52     0.0 PPM OK           16.9 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94504   27  6  7 
52 15 MAY 16  08:40:57     0.0 PPM OK           18.0 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94504   27  6  7 
52 15 MAY 16  08:41:02     0.0 PPM OK           31.6 PPM OK          37.45976 -121.94504   27  6  7 
52 15 MAY 16  08:41:07     0.0 PPM OK           28.4 PPM OK          37.45971 -121.94518   23  6  7 
52 15 MAY 16  08:41:12     0.0 PPM OK           23.6 PPM OK          37.45968 -121.94518   21  7  6
```

The intent is use the '`AUTO DATA`' as a column for `mysql` database. Currently I have the text file imported to a '`xlsb`' file where I use macros to handle to conversions and produce a '`csv`' file to upload to the database. The final goal is for the user to upload the '`txt`' file directly to the database, online. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am certainly open to researching any suggestions. Thanks in advance.